# Insert automatically auto increment value

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am trying to insert a new values into my User table in the DB, but get an error that the syntax incorrect.

In the User table I have two fields one is the ID that is primary key, auto increment and the second is KEY that is unique.

```
sql.query_insert("""insert into User values (, 'testKEY')""")
```

create table statement -

```
CREATE TABLE `Place`.`User` (
`ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`KEY` VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
UNIQUE INDEX `KEY_UNIQUE` (`KEY` ASC));
```

How can I handle the auto increment So I don't have to insert a value and it will grow automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell the query which field you are inserting and also give the schema name:

```
insert into Place.User(`key`) values ('testKey');
```

Comment: I try to do this and still I get the same problem 

"mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;" 

Maybe there is another way to do that or may I need to set my table in the DB in another way ?
Thanks !

Comment: I believe it's work, But I need it to work on my machine, I try @denny method as he show below and It's work only if I put a value into the ' ' in the query, Now why this is happened ? maybe you are know ?

Comment: Can you add  the `create table` statement to your question?

Comment: I add the create table statement, waiting for an answer.

Comment: Hmm maybe you have to add the schema name to your statement?